# rollup (w/ TypeScript, Phaser) not producing output with node-resolve plugin

Tags: node.js, typescript, plugins, phaser-framework, rollupjs

I am playing around with Phaser in Typescript, using a template repo that Phaser created. I can't get rollup to output anything when I use the `node-resolve` plugin. If I comment `node-resolve` out of the rollup config, I get the expected `./dist/game.js` file, though it doesn't seem to work properly. I've searched and tried a bunch of different things and can't seem to find the answer.

To recreate:

1. Clone https://github.com/brannonh/phaser-playground.git.
2. Run `npm install` and `npm run build`.

   - **Expected**: rollup created a `./dist/game.js` file.
   - **Actual**: `./dist/game.js` file is *not* created, and no error is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, some sleep and fresh eyes were the key. The original Phaser template project references old versions of a few of the rollup plugins (e.g., `rollup-plugin-node-resolve`). Switching my project to use the [new versions](https://github.com/rollup/plugins) (e.g., `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`) fixed this issue.